# How to use an INDIRECT inside a range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use an indirect in a range that is nested in an index.

Here's an example. Instead of:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$AR$2,MATCH(MAX(D3:AR3),D3:AR3))
```

I want to do something like this:

```
=INDEX($D$2&":"&INDIRECT(AC25),MATCH(MAX(D3:AR3),D3:AR3))
```

If AC25 is AR3, why doesn't this work?

I get the following error:
Function INDEX parameter 3 value is 24. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't have the quotes around "$D$2" - the start of the range should be a reference, not a string. So it should look like this:

```
=INDEX($D$2:INDIRECT(AC20),MATCH(MAX(D3:AR3),D3:AR3))
```

I'm assuming AC20 contains AR2 so that it is on the same row as the start of the range, D2.

[image]

---

I can't fully answer the question of why you get the message **Function INDEX parameter 3 value is 24. Valid values are between 0 and 1 inclusive**.

Assuming AR2 is blank, the first part of the Index function evaluates to the string "2:". Since this is a single value, not an array or range, the only valid value for the second part of the index is 1 or 0.

```
=Index("2:",1) is valid

=Index("2:",0) is valid

=Index("2:",24) or any other number is invalid.
```

However the error is in parameter number 2 of the Index statement, not parameter number 3, so I can only conclude that the error message itself may be incorrect and constitutes a possible bug.